# Why does Regex pattern matching not work sometimes in Scala

Tags: scala

I am trying to extract the hostname of a url in Scala 2.11.8. For some reason the pattern matching approach doesn't work and I cannot figure out why :(

```
val HOSTNAME = "^http[s]:\\/?\\/?([^:\\/\\s]+)".r
val text = "https://foo-bar.hostname.com/"

// evaluates to None
val host: Option[String] = {
  text match {
    case HOSTNAME(h) => Some(h)
    case _ =>
      None
  }
}

// evaluates to Some(foo-bar.hostname.com)
val host: Option[String] = {
  val matcher = HOSTNAME.findAllIn(text)
  if (matcher.hasNext && matcher.groupCount > 0) {
    Some(matcher.group(1))
  } else {
    None
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Scala, regular expressions are **anchored** by default - if you make it unanchored this would work:

```
val HOSTNAME = "^http[s]:\\/?\\/?([^:\\/\\s]+)".r.unanchored
```

Result would be `Some(foo-bar.hostname.com)` (I'm assuming that's what you're trying to match).

Alternatively - add a part that would match anything after the next slash:

```
val HOSTNAME = "^http[s]:\\/?\\/?([^:\\/\\s]+)\\/.*".r
```

Would return the same result.

Lastly - if you just want to parse standard URIs, you can use `java.net.URI`:

```
URI.create(text).getHost // returns foo-bar.hostname.com
```